# Low-Quality Wireframe material on Cycles for Preview Purposes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Is there any way to create a real Low-Quality Wireframe material on Cycles for Preview Purposes on Cycles Render? I need to save time by rendering...

Comment: Do you want a *Material* or a *Modifier*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use the *Wireframe* modifier to do something like this. You will want to untick the *Replace Original* checkbox. You will have about as low-res of an effect as you can get. One other important thing is *Subdivision* modifiers do affect it, so you may need to move the *Wireframe* modifier up or down the modifier stack, and you may also need to enable *Crease Edges* to keep the wireframe from deforming.

[image: Wireframe Modifier]

Sadly the *Wireframe* node in the material editor does not follow the mesh edges, but the triangulated mesh (quads are treated as two triangles, etc.)

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I don't see why this would speed up rendering times, it raises the poly count.

Comment: Yes, it increases polycounts. However it is the only way to do this. The faster way of using the *Wireframe* node doesn't work as desired, by showing a triangulated topology.